# Javascript unable to disable asp.NET linkButton

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I looked through the net and my code but I can't find the problem. Please help. My codes are below. I created a few linkbuttons which calls a postback to backend which triggers the javascript to disable/enable the linkbuttons. Unfortunately, I'm unable to do so. Can it even be done via javascript? Any idea why?

Please help... thanks

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="active" ID="tab1"><asp:LinkButton ID="tab1Link" runat="server"><strong>Basic</strong></asp:LinkButton></li>
      <li role="presentation" ID="tab2"><asp:LinkButton ID="tab2Link" runat="server"><strong>Details+</strong></asp:LinkButton></li>
      <li role="presentation" ID="tab3"><asp:LinkButton ID="tab3Link" runat="server"><strong>Location</strong></asp:LinkButton></li>
      <li role="presentation" ID="tab4"><asp:LinkButton ID="tab4Link" runat="server"><strong>Media</strong></asp:LinkButton></li>
      <li role="presentation" ID="tab5"><asp:LinkButton ID="tab5Link" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript: tabSeq('tab5', 5)"><strong>Summary</strong></asp:LinkButton></li>
    </ul>




function tabSeq(activeTab, numberOfTabs) 
{
var tabOKVal = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfTabs; i++)
{
    document.getElementById('tab'+ i).className = "";
    document.getElementById('tab'+ i+"Div").style.display = 'none';

    tabOKVal = document.getElementById('tabOK'+ i).value;
    if(tabOKVal == "OK" && i != numberOfTabs)
    {
        document.getElementById('tab' + (i+1) + 'Link').disabled = "";
        document.getElementById('tab' + (i+1) + 'Link').style.color = '#3498DB';
    }
}
document.getElementById('tab5Link').disabled = "disabled";
document.getElementById(activeTab).style.color = '#555555';
document.getElementById(activeTab).className = "active";
document.getElementById(activeTab+"Div").style.display = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
onload = function(){
   tabSeq('tab5', 5)
}

function tabSeq(activeTab, numberOfTabs) 
{
//other stuff goes here
document.getElementById('tab5Link').disabled = true;
document.getElementById(activeTab).style.color = '#555555';
document.getElementById(activeTab).className = "active";
document.getElementById(activeTab+"Div").style.display = '';
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="active" ID="tab1"><asp:LinkButton ID="tab1Link" runat="server"><strong>Basic</strong></asp:LinkButton></li>
      <li role="presentation" ID="tab2"><asp:LinkButton ID="tab2Link" runat="server"><strong>Details+</strong></asp:LinkButton></li>
      <li role="presentation" ID="tab3"><asp:LinkButton ID="tab3Link" runat="server"><strong>Location</strong></asp:LinkButton></li>
      <li role="presentation" ID="tab4"><asp:LinkButton ID="tab4Link" runat="server"><strong>Media</strong></asp:LinkButton></li>
      <li role="presentation" ID="tab5"><button ID="tab5Link" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript: tabSeq('tab5', 5)"><strong>Summary</strong></button></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

LinkButtons are ASP.NET server controls and they are not accessible by the control ID value which you see in design time.

You can rewrite the js code as follows:

```
document.getElementById("<%= tab5Link.ClientID %>").disabled = "disabled";
```

Please note that this can be done only the JS code is on the same page.

Comment: Thanks! I gave up and did it via server end in the end. But your explanation is correct. But in that case why can I get asp:Textbox  via javascript? Not doubting you but just a bit inconsistent in how things are done :/

Comment: I'm not getting your question. Can you please show me the place where you access the TextBox control via JS? Just copy paste the code. :)

Comment: It's not a really a question. It's more of a observation. You stated that "ASP.NET server controls and they are not accessible by the control ID value which you see in design time" but in actual fact, you can access  other ASP constructs using the control ID eg. Textboxes. My point was that not being to access LinkButtons as you would Textboxes seem inconsistent. :)

Comment: All the server controls(Buttons, TextBoxes, etc.. etc) cannot be accessed by their ID value in JavaScript code. We should get the clientID to access them.